# Android 9: Cleartext HTTP traffic not permitted in webview

Tags: android, http, flutter, webview, android-manifest

I am using the `webview_flutter` plugin to load a page hosted on localhost(server created with dart, on the phone) but I get `net::ERR_CLEARTEXT_NOT_PERMITTED`  and I can't make the server HTTPS.

I've implemented all the solutions [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45940861/android-8-cleartext-http-traffic-not-permitted) but none of these work:

- adding a network_security_config.xml file
- adding the `android:usesCleartextTraffic` option

Is there any other solution to this?

Comment: hi mate, managed to solve it? Facing same problem here.

Comment: I didn't need to use a webserver anymore since webview_flutter can load local files anyways. Idk how I missed that. To load locally store files (html, css and js) you have to provide the full path of the .html file using `
final directory = (await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory()).path;
var url =  "file:///$directory/path/to/index.html";` and it will load it correctly

Comment: Thing is I need to get the content from a web server.

Comment: I reimplemented everything from the top 7 google results about this problem and it worked in the end

Answer (score 0):

I'm an android developer,let me tell you.

Open the android manifest file(both debug and release),and add

```
android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
```

to the **application** tag

```
<application
    android:name="io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication"
    android:label="..."
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:usesCleartextTraffic="true">
```

release file path `android/app/src/main/AndroidManifest.xml`
debug file path `android/app/src/debug/AndroidManifest.xml`

[image]

[image]